# My JS is not working in codepen but working fine in the console

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment, codepen

https://codepen.io/sristi27/pen/mdejzrv
This is the link to my codepen file.I have also added jQuery to it but the JS part is not being shown in the live view.
What is wrong with my code?
Js file:

```
var square=document.querySelectorALL(".squares");
var colors=["rgb(255, 0, 0)","rgb(255, 255, 0)","rgb(0, 0, 255)","rgb(0, 255, 0)","rgb(255, 0, 255)","rgb(0, 255, 255)"];

for(var i=0;i<square.length;i++){
    square[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: Its `querySelectorAll()` not `querySelectorALL`

Comment: Interesting..How it is working in the console ? though querySelectorALL is not a valid function.

Answer (score 1):

You have typo: querySelectorALL should be querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

We need to remove `dot` from `getElementsByClassName` function and here we go.

Here is link for it.

```js
var square=document.getElementsByClassName("squares");
var colors=["rgb(255, 0, 0)","rgb(255, 255, 0)","rgb(0, 0, 255)","rgb(0, 255, 0)","rgb(255, 0, 255)","rgb(0, 255, 255)"];

for(var i=0;i<square.length;i++){
    square[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:grey;
  text-align:center;
}

.squares{
  width:30%;
  background:purple;
  float:left;
  padding-bottom:30%;
  margin:1.66%;
  
}
#container{
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:600px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head><title>color grading</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The Great RGB Game</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="squares"></div>
      <div class="squares"></div>
      <div class="squares"></div>
      <div class="squares"></div>
      <div class="squares"></div>
      <div class="squares"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```